# Is it possible to display image in its original size without getting resize so as to fit the screen in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, android-canvas

I tried to display an floor plan on the android emulator but the image displayed is always resize to fit the screen when i run the apps. Is that ways where i can display the image without getting ti resize to fit the screen?

Comment: Yes, thats's possible. What have you tried yet (that didn't work)?

Comment: [Screenshot](https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s720x720/293337_10150314275939444_608974443_7783562_1025673010_n.jpg)

The floor plan in the screen got resized and fit into the screen. If i'm not wrong, it isn't that small and i would need this floor plan to display the user's current position and wouldn't want user to zoom into to look for his/her current position.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the [ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) to make it behave how you prefer.